# How do I find my latest comments?

Tags: support, comments

Sometimes it's nice to ask OP to specify some details before answering/flagging/downvoting, but they may avoid replying to a comment. In that case, one may proceed with answering/flagging/downvoting. But as far as I can see, there's no easy way to find those "unreplied" comments (or at least my latest comments). Is there? (if there is no such feature, this should be turned into a feature request)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just go to the "Activity" tab on your profile page, select "All actions" and then the tab "comments".

From here, you are able to see the comments you've posted, ordered by the time at which you posted them.

You can also use that link directly. For example, your comments on Stack Overflow can be found here:

https://stackoverflow.com/users/current/?tab=activity&sort=comments

Or for any user, when you know the user ID (easily found from the URL of their profile page):

https://stackoverflow.com/users/<user-id>?tab=activity&sort=comments

You can't see every comment though: if the comment was deleted, you can't see it.
Also, comments on deleted posts are not listed here.
But deleted comments, and comments on deleted posts, are unlikely to be relevant anyway.

Comment: *you are able to see every comment you've posted* - that's not quite the case. It won't list deleted comments (but then they're completely gone to non-mods anyway), or comments that are on posts that are deleted (you'll still be able to see the comment if you can remember which post it was on and have 10k rep by going to the post though).

Comment: @JonClements Thanks, edited that in.

Comment: Or, if you have accounts on multiple SE sites: http://stackexchange.com/users/current/?tab=activity&sort=comments (with stackexchange instead of stackoverflow). That's what I use.